# How to loop from the first to the last value of a table in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

What can I write to get all the id numbers of a table from the first until the last one?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRICE(
      L_CUST_ID PRICELIST.CUSTOMERS_ID%TYPE,
      L_ITEMS_ID PRICELIST.ITEMS_ID%TYPE,
      P_PRICELIST_PRICE NUMBER)
)
  RETURNS NUMBER AS
BEGIN 
 FOR I IN 1..< last id of customers> LOOP
   FOR I IN 1..< last id of items> LOOP
     INSERT INTO PRICE
      (CUSTOMERS_ID, ITEMS_ID, P_PRICE)
      VALUES
      ( L_CUST_ID, L_ITEMS_ID,ROUND(dbms_random.value(0,15),4)); 
   END LOOP;
 END LOOP;
RETURN L_CUST_ID;
END PRICE;
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are you sure you need a loop there? Usually working on a set of records is the way to go.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I WANT FOR EACH COMBINATION OF CUSTOMERS AND ITEMS A RANDOM PRICE.

Comment: @GEO don't type comments in all caps, it is considered shouting and rude.

Comment: You can randomize set based column values just as well.

Comment: "I want random prices" has nothing to do with "why are you using loops instead of a single SQL statement". Is it your belief that you MUST use loops (there is no other way), or are you required to use PL/SQL code instead of a single, trivial SQL statement for some other reason which you didn't share with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to use nested loops; for small data sets, you won't notice any difference, but - if tables contain many rows, processing row-by-row is slow-by-slow and performance will suffer.

Therefore, why wouldn't you just cross join those tables? Here's an example.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> select * From customers;

CUSTOMERS_ID NAME
------------ ------
           1 Little
           2 Foot

SQL> select * From items;

  ITEMS_ID NAME
---------- -------
        10 Gloves
        11 Matches
        12 Bottle
```

Insert cross-joined data:

```
SQL> insert into price (customers_id, items_id, p_price)
  2  select c.customers_id, i.items_id, round(dbms_random.value(0, 15), 4)
  3  from customers c cross join items i;

6 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from price;

CUSTOMERS_ID   ITEMS_ID    P_PRICE
------------ ---------- ----------
           1         10    11,5653
           1         11     8,9442
           1         12     4,4143
           2         10     5,3387
           2         11     14,602
           2         12    14,2723

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it  runs. Can i also call another function that i have created ( The add _pricelist) instead  of insert into and get th same job done?

Comment: You're welcome. If your goal is to perform inserts, then use a **procedure**, not a function - function's primary goal is to return some value. Yours actually *is* returning L_CUST_ID which is just the same as value you passed to it, so - not very useful, is it?